# Javascript easy array declartion option like perl

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, perl

In perl we can declare the array with `qw` or  `quote word` take make  each word is taken into individual array cell.
eg.

```
 my @arr= qw( hello
           world)
```

or else you need to quote each word
eg

```
my @arr = ("hello" ,  "word");
```

Is there something similar in javascript as sometime it need lot of formatting to simple declare array.

Comment: Use an array literal?

Comment: `const arr = ["hello", "world"];` ?

Comment: Alternative you could use a tagged template string: const s = v => v; const arr = s` hello ${} world `; ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need, for this specific case: `const arr = 'hello world'.split(' ');`.

Edit:
Check out the docs for `String.split` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Also, read something on types in JavaScript, if you are wondering why it is possible to call this method on string literal, as I did.

Comment: persnaps you could explain how it works? maybe link to the docs for `split()`?